# If $U \sim Unif(0,1)$, why is $P\left(U \leq \frac{f(X)}{cg(X)}\right) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{f(x)/cg(x)}g(x) du dx$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that $X$ is a random variable distributed according to density $g$. and that $f$ is a separate density function. Let $U \sim Unif(0,1)$. I am wondering why:

$$
P\left(U \leq \frac{f(X)}{cg(X)}\right) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{f(x)/cg(x)}g(x) du dx
$$

Is there a simple way to see this?

Answer (score 1):

It is presumed here that $X$ and $U$ are independent r.v.'s. and also that the ratio $\frac{f(x)}{cg(x)}\leq 1$ for all $x$.

Joint density function for $(U,X)$ is the product of p.d.f.'s: $$f_{(U,X)}(u,x)=1_{(0,1)}(u)g(x).$$
Here $1_{(0,1)}(u)$ is equal to $1$ for $u\in(0,1)$ and $0$ otherwise.

Then for $D=\left\{(x,u)\,:\,u\leq \frac{f(x)}{cg(x)}\right\}$
$$
P\left(U \leq \frac{f(X)}{cg(X)}\right) = P\left((U,X)\in D \right)=\iint_D  f_{(U,X)}(u,x)dudx.
$$
To integrate over $D$ one can allow $x$ to run along $\mathbb R$, and for any $x$ allow $u$ to be in range $0, \frac{f(x)}{cg(x)}$. If this value is greater 1, one should integrate up to $1$.

Finally
$$P\left(U \leq \frac{f(X)}{cg(X)}\right) =
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{f(x)/cg(x))}1_{(0,1)}(u)g(x) du dx=
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\min(1,\,f(x)/cg(x))}g(x) du dx.$$

This is the same as initial integral if $\frac{f(x)}{cg(x)}\leq 1$ for all $x$.